# Result after scanning with clamAV

Tags: clamav, scanning

I recently installed Linux on my laptop. To be on the safe side I decided to install clamAV. After first scanning I received:  PUA.Http.Exploit.CVE_2015_1692

Is that something I should worry about?

Is clamAV + Firewall enough or do I need stronger protection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you googled "CVE_2015_1692", the description would have showed you:

> Microsoft Internet Explorer 7 through 11 allows user-assisted remote
>   attackers to read the clipboard contents via crafted web script, aka
>   "Internet Explorer Clipboard Information Disclosure Vulnerability."

So, if you're running versions 7 through 11 of Microsoft Internet Explorer...

ClamAV (did you read `man -k clamav`?) plus "Firewall" (do you mean `UFW` (did you read `man ufw`)) "enough"? No. No tool or combination of tools can make you more secure without your understanding. Nothing (except unplug & bury in cement) can make a computer system "secure".

What network environment is your system connected to? T4, DSL, Fiber, WiFi? What data/capabilities are you trying to "secure"? Against whom? Have you considered "rubber hose cryptanalysis"?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for a quick reply. CVE_2015_1692 showed up when I was scanning Xubuntu partition. I don't use Windows 8.1 partition very often and I don't use Internet Explorer.  I'm trying to keep Windows partition offline. I'm just using it as a platform for music production. So what's the best way to secure Linux partition against viruses and malware (nothing in specific)and do I have to worry about that scan result? My system is connected to WiFi.