# Firefox Trojans

Tags: antivirus

I have run ClamAv on Ubuntu 15.10 several times in the last 10 days.
Every time it comes up with Firefox harbouring Trojans and what I would think are possibly cookies. I suspect the Trojans are false positives but am not sure.

[image: ClamAv scan results]

Has anyone similar experiences or can they give me some information which will give me peace of mind?

Comment: clamav (and all linux AV AFIK) is notorious for false positives. You need to read the message clam is giving and follow up. - example - http://askubuntu.com/questions/685661/result-after-scanning-with-clamav/ . If you need help, post the results from clamav

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I decided to send a days takings to Clam Av but have not heard from them yet.

Comment: If you need help, post the message you are getting from clam AV, otherwise we can not help you.

Comment: Thank you Bodhi.zazen. I am having difficulty in doing that. I am not allowed to attach the file. I have edited and put the Clam Av output on the main message I thought but can not see it now. I will try some more .

Comment: Use a pastebin and paste the link. I doubt anyone is going to read more then one or two, so read the output and paste one or two to get a start.